# MVC Controller can't fire the view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, multithreading, model-view-controller

Hi the view can't fire but it's is already hit its controller.
Is it a deadlock? Because I'm using GetAsync to get the HttpResponse Message.
Here is my code.

```
   private bool GetCoordinates(string address)
    {
        bool result = false;

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode("http://locationInfo/GetLocation?address=" + address));

        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
        new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("").Result;
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            JObject objs = JObject.Parse(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
            int count = 0;
            string[] cor = new string[2];
            foreach (var item in objs)
            {
                if(item.Key.ToString() == "location") {
                    foreach (var it in item.Value)
                    {
                        if (count <= 1)
                        {
                            cor[count] = it.ToList()[0].ToString();
                        }
                        count++;
                    }
                }
            }

            Xcor = cor[0];
            Ycor = cor[1];
            result = response.IsSuccessStatusCode;
        }

        response.Dispose();
        client.Dispose();
        return result;
    }

}
```

--> The Index can't show the view.

Comment: You are returning `bool` so how a view will be shown ?

Comment: This is only a function that calls inside the controller

Comment: Show the controller code as well.

Comment: What does _"the view can't fire but it's is already hit its controller"_ mean exactly?

Comment: This is the function I suspected causing DEADLOCK. This is inside of my actionresult return Method. However I can't post to this thread I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the controller to return boolean value after all your process, then make this method as an *Action Method(here we can return values to view)*.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(string address)
{       
    ModelClass model = new ModelClass();
    model.yourModelVal = GetCoordinates(address);
    return View(model);
}

public bool GetCoordinates(string address)
{
    bool result = false;

    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode("http://locationInfo/GetLocation?address=" + address));

    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
    new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("").Result;
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        JObject objs = JObject.Parse(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
        int count = 0;
        string[] cor = new string[2];
        foreach (var item in objs)
        {
            if(item.Key.ToString() == "location") {
                foreach (var it in item.Value)
                {
                    if (count <= 1)
                    {
                        cor[count] = it.ToList()[0].ToString();
                    }
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }

        Xcor = cor[0];
        Ycor = cor[1];
        result = response.IsSuccessStatusCode;
    }

    response.Dispose();
    client.Dispose();
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to return `View`. Now you are returning `bool`. `ReturnType` must be `ActionResult`